# What could cause a replacement A/C condenser fan motor to only run for 3 minutes?

Tags: hvac

Just replaced a GE 5KCP39FG Condenser fan motor with an AC Smith FSE1026SF.  HVAC Counter sales told me it was the right one and gave me a Partners Choice Capacitor 01-0085 to match.

Old motor 3 wires and no reversible plug.  New Motor 4 wires (brown/white is new wire) and has reversing plug.  Took picture of old motor installation and confirmed at HVAC counter sales how to wire new motor.  Old Black is new Black (goes to plug module on condenser frame, Old Yellow is new white (Goes to 4 prong on Capacitor), Old Brown is new Brown and Brown/White (goes to 2 prong Fan on capaciter), Blue from condenser chassis (goes to 3 prong HERM on Capacitor).

Turned on electricty and AC and everything started like a champ for about 3 minutes then the fan cut out and I noticed the fan moter was very hot.  Also, it was not near the RPMs I remember.

So I fiddled.  Took off Brown and White and turned on electricity.  Condenser fired up , but no fan.  Touched Brown/White to capacitor and fan started.  Once it was spinning, I untouched the Brown/WHiite and the RPMs increased to full speed, then cut out after 2 minutes due to motor heating up.

Last item. When comparing motor info, all the info between the two is the same except for amperage.  Old motor was 1.4, new motor is 2.0.

What can I do and is it the motor amperage?

Comment: I'd say it's a good chance it's the amperage; the new one is trying to draw up to 2A, while the supporting circuitry is only expecting to supply a max. of ~1.4A

Comment: @James, did you get the problem fixed? what was the actual problem. i got the same problem in my AC unit today. Please update the thread so that everyone can benefit from it

Answer (score 3):

I had a capacitor replaced once.  Everything seemed to work fine, until 5 minutes after the a/c guy left, then the fan overheated and stopped.  I couldn't get him to come back, so I investigated and found that he hooked up the wires to the capacitor backwards; the fan was connected to the "run" prong on the capacitor and the motor to the "fan" prong.  I switched it back and it's been running fine ever since.